# IndentationError - expected an indented block

Tags: python

I get the IndentationError: expected an indented block.
I was trying to copy all the contents form webpage to a txt file. Not sure what the error is but in my homework found that indented error occure if there is a combination of space and tabs. Beginning with python can someone help. Thanks in Advance.

```
import requests
url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/article/4166013-t-t-q1-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript?part=single'
data = requests.get(url)
with open('file.txt','w') as out_f:
out_f.write(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Please review the StackOverflow help center as to the types of questions which are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Per the help-center "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

StackOverflow isn't intended to be used to be a general programming guide. There are a number of beginner's Python resources which can be found by Googling, such as https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike many other languages Python uses indentation to create code blocks. Python code blocks are usually indented with 4 or 8 spaces. You should pay attention to the indentation of the code you find online when copy/pasting. All that said, copy/pasting random code off the Internet is a good way to get a virus or a 0 on a lab assignment.

Here is some more details about Python indentation: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

Answer (score 3):

`with` expects an indented block is to follow, so do this:

```
with open('file.txt','w') as out_f:
    out_f.write(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

This is the same as when you indent for an `if`, `elif`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `try`, etc.

Comment: I think, in general (there might be some exceptions I'm unaware of), python uses colons `:` to show it is expecting an indented block.

Comment: @AdamDadvar `if condition: print('foo')` is valid Python. Otherwise, if there is a newline, it is true colons indicate an expected indented block.

Comment: @Tomothy32 very true, hadn't considered the in-line case!